# Html.RadioButton of asp.net MVC generates id and name same

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

```
<%=Html.RadioButton("BookType", "1")  %> C#
<%=Html.RadioButton("BookType", "2")  %> VB
```

Above code generates Below code

```
<input id="BookType" name="BookType" type="radio" value="1" >C#
<input id="BookType" name="BookType" type="radio" value="2" >VB
```

I need same name but different ids

I want output like

*

```
<input id="rdoCSharp" name="BookType" type="radio" value="1" >C#
<input id="rdoVb" name="BookType" type="radio" value="2" >VB
```

*

Comment: I did this years ago in MVC1. Really - I still have to do this? What's the reason apart from backward compatbility. Why isn't the default to output no ID at all?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can override the defaults by passing the attributes you wish to apply using an [overload of the RadioButton method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492690.aspx):

```
<%=Html.RadioButton("BookType", "1", new { id = "yourId" })  %> C#
```

Comment: this is so broken since early mvc and it's a shame that mvc cannot render radio buttons properly still on version 5.

Comment: I'm just getting into MVC and am trying to understand this concept. What is the big benefit of using these simple Html helpers? Why not just do `<input id="rdoCSharp" name="BookType" type="radio" value="1">` and sub in individual <%= Model.Whatever %> as needed? Trusting Microsoft to generate your HTML sounds like a terrible idea. They've failed with HTML/CSS time after time.

Comment: @xr280xr: MVC also injects things like all the validation attributes into the HTML as well, so not quite as trivial as you might have imagined.

Comment: @xr280xr Using the `FooFor( m => m.Property )` syntax means that your `name=""` attributes will be automatically generated, which reduces bugs if you change your viewmodels and means you can compose forms in a nested fashion, it also means you can do loops. Point is, HTML Helpers are a *Very Good Thing(TM)* - that just has the occasional bug like this.

Answer (score 9):

```
<%= Html.RadioButton("BookType", "1", new { id = "rdoCSharp" }) %> C#
<%= Html.RadioButton("BookType", "2", new { id = "rdoVb" }) %> VB
```

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
<%=Html.RadioButton("BookType", "1",new{@id="BookType1"})  %> C#
<%=Html.RadioButton("BookType", "2",new{@id="BookType2"})  %> VB
```