# jquery multiple radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

below is my jquery code, how can i change it so that i am not repeating same code due to the fact that variables are changing? it is for multiple radio buttons using hide/show.

my radio button has a class `"someclass"`:

```
 <input class="someclass" id="different1" type="radio" value="Yes" /> <input class="someclass" id="different1" type="radio" value="No" />
    <input class="someclass" id="different2" type="radio" value="Yes" /><input class="someclass" id="different2" type="radio" value="No" />  
    <input class="someclass" id="different3" type="radio" value="Yes" /><input class="someclass" id="different3" type="radio" value="No" />
```

my divs each have same class:

```
<div class="divclass" style="display:none" id="notthesame1"></div>
<div class="divclass" style="display:none" id="notthesame2"></div>
<div class="divclass" style="display:none" id="notthesame3"></div>

$("input[name='different1']").click(function () {
            $('#notthesame1').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Yes') ? 'block' : 'none');
        });

      $("input[name='different2']").click(function () {
          $('#notthesame2').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Yes') ? 'block' : 'none');
      });

      $("input[name='different2']").click(function () {
          $('#notthesame2').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Yes') ? 'block' : 'none');
      });
```

Comment: `name` attribute should be same in order to group options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you cannot have same `id` for more than two elements:

```
<input class="someclass" id="different1" type="radio" value="Yes" />
<input class="someclass" id="different1" type="radio" value="No" />
```

Both the `id`s match. But you need to have `name` be the same. So change it to:

```
<input class="someclass" name="different1" type="radio" value="Yes" />
<input class="someclass" name="different1" type="radio" value="No" />
```

Use `data-*` attributes to make stuff easy for you. Or, give the same `class` as an `id` to the `<div>`:

```
<input class="someclass" name="different1" type="radio" value="Yes" />
<input class="someclass" name="different1" type="radio" value="No" />
```

My solution for you would be something like this:

```
<input class="tab-input" name="tab1" type="radio" value="Yes" />
<input class="tab-input" name="tab1" type="radio" value="No" />
<div class="tab" id="tab1"></div>
```

And in the JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $(".tab-input").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Yes")
            $("#" + $(this).attr("name")).show();
        else
            $("#" + $(this).attr("name")).hide();
    });
});
```

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/xuyodirudu**

Comment: I tried this however, it is hiding/showing the radio buttons rather than the actual div.

Comment: @Menew Can you kindly share a fiddle that does? I am definitely sure, you didn't copy it correctly! `:)`

Comment: I did, and btw, c# mvc radiobuttonFor is the one adding all the extra IDs not me.

Comment: @Menew Aha... You didn't say you are using C#.

Comment: the answer worked after i applied this solution to get rid of all the extra ids: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291975/html-radiobutton-of-asp-net-mvc-generates-id-and-name-same

Comment: @Menew Added a fiddle for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the amount of jquery you are writing you could try using event delegation and wrapping your inputs in a parent element.

Edit: Forget what I said about ids, was bad advice before, it's different for inputs.

```
<div id="radioboxes">
  <input type="radio" class="radio" value="yes">
  <input type="radio" class="radio" value="no">
  <input type="radio" class="radio" value="yes">
  <input type="radio" class="radio" value="no">
  <input type="radio" class="radio" value="yes">
  <input type="radio" class="radio" value="no">
</div>

<script>
  $('#radioboxes').on("click", "input", function() {
    var radio = $( this );
    radio.css('display', (radio.val() === 'Yes') ? 'block', 'none');
  })
</script>
```

Comment: c# mvc "radiobuttonFor" is assigning all the ids, not me.